# SQL group summing

Tags: sql, sum

Okay, say that I have two columns, Person and Donation. With, for example, these as rows:

```
+++++++++++++++
Fred | $1000 
Fred |  $500 
Bob  | $1000
Bob  | $7000
Sally|  $500
Joe  |  $100  
+++++++++++++++
```

How could I get it to display the following?

```
+++++++++++++++
Fred | $1500
Bob  | $8000
Sally|  $500
Joe  |  $100  
+++++++++++++++
```

In other words, how could I group together all the donations under a certain person, and sum them up? What would be an example query that would accomplish this? (If at all possible, in a general way, that does not involve individually naming the people in the select/sum clause)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a `GROUP BY` clause with an aggregate function (like `SUM`) the aggregate is calculated for each group.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Donation) FROM Donations GROUP BY Name
```

If you want to get more specific results, like those people with total donations more than $500, introduce a `HAVING` clause. This is sort of like a `WHERE` for aggregate results:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Donation) FROM Donations GROUP BY Name 
    HAVING SUM(Donation) > 500
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2de84/1/0

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the link, it looks like an excellent tool.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(a.donation),a.person from a_table as a group by a.person;
```

a_table is your table;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query for this:

```
SELECT Name "Name", SUM(Donation) "Donation" FROM Donations GROUP BY Name
```